# How can I rewrite this SQL using the Django ORM, it uses, lag, partition and a select query as a table for the join

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I have a query that works in SQL but I'm struggling to come up with the correct ORM:

`SELECT page, first_name, last_name, SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (end_time - start_time))) AS total_active_time_seconds FROM ( SELECT page, "user_id", event_type, created_at AS start_time, LEAD(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY page ORDER BY created_at) AS end_time FROM analytics_log WHERE (event_type = 'page_landed' OR event_type = 'moved_to_another_tab') ) as event_intervals left JOIN profiles_user ON user_id=profiles_user.id WHERE event_type = 'page_landed' GROUP BY page, first_name, last_name;`

The models in question are

`
class Log(models.Model):

```
page = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, db_index=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
user = models.ForeignKey('profiles.User', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
session_id = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
event_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
meta_data = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

class User(AbstractUser):
#regular user model fields

`

I've looked at this example but its not quite the same: [Partitioning with lag](https://blog.devgenius.io/advanced-sql-part-2-window-functions-partition-by-lag-lead-exclude-with-django-orm-8b78455770e)

Basically I'm trying to figure out how long someone spend on a certain task from the logs, but they could leave the tab, come back, leave again etc.

I've got the SQL working mostly as I want, I don't have enough data to be certain yet, but it seems  close enough to real times. I'm struggling with adding the Query as a join. We can easily join the two tables over the user, but I don't want to just join them I want to join over the output of the first query in the sql FROM clause.